# Can't import modules

Tags: python, django

I've searched for this problem and tried different solutions but can't fix it.
In my Django project I have different apps and a non-app directory called 'testing_utils' with modules which serve for a testing purposes. In particular I want to import all available models to file dummy_factory.py. However when I simply import modules from my apps like so:

```
from abc import ABC
from datetime import date
from users.models import User
```

I get the error message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'

Which is strange since I definetley can import models to some_app.views.py and access them.
Here's an example of my project's directory:

```
/home/user/dev/project/
▸ project/
▾ testing_utils/
    dummy_factory.py
▾ users/
  ▸ __pycache__/
  ▸ migrations/
  ▸ templates/
  ▸ tests/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    views.py
  manage.py*
```

Comment: It's possible that there is a permission problem

Comment: @Aviation6 Do you mean permissions for file like 'read-only'

Comment: Something along the lines of not being able to see inside where pip saves python libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/home/user/dev/project/` needs to be in your `PYTHONPATH` to be able to be imported.

If your `testing_utils` is meant to be local only, the easiest way to accomplish this is to add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/dev/project/')
```

... in `dummy_factory.py` *before* importing the module.

Solutions that would be more proper would be to install `users` (how exactly you'd make your package installable depends on your system and what version of Python and Pip you need to support), or to use a virtualenv that automatically adds the right directories to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I should've specify this in the original post: I use venv for this project and everything like users is an app and is registered in settings. The problem is within directory which is not an app.

Comment: I've fixed this issue. By adding 'import sys sys.apth.append' I've traced another issue and then I realised the problem was that I tried to check my module by running it with 'python dummy_factory.py' when in fact I should've done it in manage.py shell. Thanks.